# Task scheduler VS GPO do not allow storage of password

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, task-scheduler

I have a scheduled task in one of my DC, running to check LastLogon date of AD accounts in each DCs everyday.

The task was previously running in a Win 2003 DC without problem but now we are going to decom that. And since migrated to Win 2008 R2, I face a few limitations:

1. Our environment do have the following GPO enabled: Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication. This has restricted me from choosing "Run whether user logged on or not" WITHOUT ticking the "Do not store password.."
2. The task just would not run if I tick the "Do not store password.", since it is going to retrieve info from other DCs.

Result: I can only choose "Run only when user is logged on", and as it stated, the task will run only when the service ID is logged on to the DC. The task is quite critical and since session get logged off from time to time (by operator or by reboot of server), it has no assurance the task will run everyday.

I would like to know without disable this GPO, is there any workaround for case like this? (by the way why Win 2003 is not affected by this?) I believe all of your system should have plenty of scheduled tasks, how do you all system admin handle that? Do you convince your security team that you need the GPO disabled? (I will try that only if there is no other solution)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use something like FireDaemon to run the service within Session 0 interactively.  That would allow you to keep your current GPO enabled.

Comment: @TheCleaner Seems like using the third party software is the only solution, however it doesn't look quite straightforward as you mentioned I need to run it within session 0 interactively. Think disable the policy is my best option now. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Welcome.  FireDaemon will run in Session 0 interactively.  You can switch back and forth between that session within FireDaemon as needed to see the program.

Comment: Not sure whether this is correct, I finally come out with a "solution" to run the task as a windows service, then restart the service at specific time daily to initial the task. The restart of service can be scheduled to run whether the user logged on or not.